# Doctrine query builder ManyToMany with join table

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I try to build something like this query by doctrine query builder:

```
SELECT m.id
FROM product p, model m
  INNER JOIN product_model pm ON (m.id = pm.model_id)
WHERE p.id = pm.product_id AND m.serial = ? AND p.id = ?
```

Table `product_model` is a JoinTable in `ManyToMany Unidirectional relationship. I use code below:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder
            ->select('m.id')
            ->from(Model::class, 'm')
            ->join(Product::class, 'p', Join::ON, '1 = 1')
            ->where('m.serial.serial = :serial')
            ->andWhere('p.productId.id = :productId')
            ->setParameters([
                'serial'    => (string)$serial,
                'productId' => $productId->value(),
            ]);
        $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
        $results = $query->getOneOrNullResult();
```

But when I try to dump SQL of this query I got:

```
SELECT m0_.id AS id_0 
FROM model m0_ 
  INNER JOIN product p1_ ON (1 = 1) 
WHERE m0_.serial = ? AND p1_.id = ?
```

And result of this query Isn't what I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I need another entity class for product_model tabel with composite key and litle changes in query:

```
$queryBuilder
            ->select('m.id')
            ->from(Model::class, 'm')
            ->join(ProductModel::class, 'pm', Join::WITH, $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('m.id', 'pm.modelId'))
            ->where('m.serial.serial = :serial')
            ->andWhere('pm.productId = :productId')
            ->setParameters(
                [
                    'serial'    => (string)$serial,
                    'productId' => $productId->value(),
                ]
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be more simple.

If the join table contains only the id and no other data it shouldn't be declared as an Entity. I've never used the join tables in any project when workin with Doctrine.

cf. : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html

In my opinion this should work :

```
$queryBuilder
        ->select('m.id')
        ->from(Model::class, 'm')
        ->join(Product::class, 'p')
        ->where('m.serial.serial = :serial')
        ->setParameters(
            [
                'serial'    => (string)$serial,
            ]
        );
```

Comment: I forgot yout 2nd parameter, productId but I hope you understand what I mean, I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with your mapping definition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).